# dropzone does not show form after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone and I came to a problem that the dropzone does not detect the form after my ajax call.  In the success of the ajax I tried to add `Dropzone.discover();` after I put the form.

**Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://xxxxxxx/?controller=Sellers&action=showAllProducts',
  data: postData,
  success: function (data) {
    $('#showProducts').html(data);
    Dropzone.discover();
  },
  error: function (error) {
  }

});
```

**The `data`:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <?php
      foreach($products as $product){
    ?>
    <!--HTML starts here!!!-->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" style="width:358px; height:676px;">
      <?php echo '<form action="app/public/templates/control_panel/upload.php"
class="dropzone"
id="myDropzone">
</form>';?>
      <!--HTML ends here!!!-->
    </div>
    <?php
}

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Now I know that the dropzone is working because when I put the form directly on the page, it works like it should.  I think the problem is my forms are coming after the dropzone is fired, but I tried so many things and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to use the discover function you must set the `autodiscover` to be false before you call the `Dropzone.discover()`.

After that, you can call `Dropzone.discover()` in the ajax success.